# How do I delete or reinitialize a 'new' variable?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, new-operator

Before you report me for asking a commonly-asked question, hear me out.

I am writing a program to read from a datalogger using C# and windows forms. Each of the channels can mean different things, such as lift, drag, and pressure. I plan to make these channels configurable. Here is how such a channel is initialized:

```
private Channel Lift_Channel = new Channel(1);
```

This initializes Lift_Channel as a Channel object that references channel 1 on the logger.

However, the constructor method Channel(int) is the only method I can use to set the channel. If I want Lift_Channel to point to channel 2, I would like to do something like this.

```
delete Lift_Channel;
Lift_Channel = new Channel(2);
```

I feel like if I can't delete Lift_Channel then recreate it, I will have memory leak errors because the Channel(1) data will be floating around.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you're coming from C++, I can see why you'd ask this question. In C#, memory management (with a few exceptions) is taken care of for you.

Comment: What exactly is happening when you call `new Channel(1)`? Is some other resource getting allocated somewhere? If the resource is unmanaged memory, then the standard thing to do is have Channel implement IDisposable and a destructor.

Comment: @mikez C# doesn't have destructors. It has finalizers.

Comment: @DanielMann I find it strange that people insist C# does not have destructors. The spec defines them as destructors (see section 10.13 "Destructors") and nowhere refers to finalizers as such (outside a few passing references to GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers).

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly where I was coming from was C++.

But man, C# is awesome so far.

Answer (score 4):

Nope, nothing to delete. After you re-assign it, Lift_Channel will no longer point to the old memory address, and the memory will be cleaned up.

Answer (score 4):

In C++, any object allocated on the heap must be deleted or it will leak memory.  In a typical .NET managed app that only uses managed code, developers don't have to worry about deleting an object when they are done using it.  This is because .NET has a very nice and efficient garbage collector.  It keeps track of all references to objects and when the last reference to an object is no longer valid, it then deletes the object on its own.  The garbage collector typically runs in about the same time as a memory page fault, so it is pretty efficient.

There are times when you might need to implement some code to handle cleaning up an object if it is using unmanaged code.  .NET provides an interface for this called [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  The main idea behind this is for the code that instantiates the object to call the Dispose method to perform cleanup.  If someone forgets to do this, then the garbage collector ends up calling your finalizer method as a fail safe.  The finalizer needs to implement a call to the Dispose method.  An example of this is shown in the link above.

The garbage collector (GC) runs automatically in the background and stops all active managed threads before it does any clean up work.  Part of this clean up work involves compaction of memory and it can move memory around.  If you have calls into unmanaged code that use pointers or references to managed data, then that data should be pinned in memory so that the GC won't move it.  This can be done with the [Fixed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/f58wzh21%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) statement for use within a given method or the [GCHandle.Alloc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a95009h1.aspx) method for longer periods of time that can be used outside of the method it was declared in.  The GCHandle Free method should be called to release the pin.  Pinning memory requires that the code be marked as unsafe.

.NET provides a class called [GC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that can be used to help control the garbage collector.  For example, if you have objects that are using a large amount of memory and wish to wait for the memory to be released before proceeding, then the following methods should be called to accomplish this after setting them to null:

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Answer (score 1):

.Net garbage collects allocated items that cannot be reached any more. collection.  The garbage collector runs periodically and will reclaim memory for objects that are not reachable by anything else.

By assigning via a new `new`, the memory formerly associated with a variable (before the reassignment) will not longer be reachable (assuming that variable was the only thing referring to it).  So the old object becomes unreachable, then the garbage collector will pick it up the next time it runs.

Hence, there is no `delete` operator.

1. You can assign null to a variable, to make it unreachable or
2. you can assign a new object reference to a variable.
3. Finally, you can use the IDisposable interface to ensure disposal at the end of a block of code.

All of those actions achieve the effect of a delete.  (Eventually, if the item is unreachable, it will be "deleted when the garbage collector runs).